# Why didn't Tesla use his machine to make money before selling it to Angier?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

In The Prestige, Nikola Tesla builds the magician Rupert Angier a teleport machine that also ends up duplicating the object placed inside of it. It is further revealed that Tesla is bankrupt, and that Angier is his last financier.

If Tesla was so desperate for money, why did he not use his machine to create funds before he sold it to Angier? I guess it's true that Edison was a better businessman...

Comment: From a historical point of view, the attitude is accurate. Nikola Tesla was quite famous for spending years on an invention, only to discard it after he got it working. He was far more interested in the technical challenges than any reward or fame. It was this lack of business acumen that allowed Edison and others to take advantage of his genius repeatedly throughout the years.

Comment: Sure would have made sense to put a stack of money in the machine and duplicate it a few dozen times!

Comment: This is one of those questions where you should double check whether you are on movies.se or hsm.se before even thinking about an answer...

Comment: Because cash has serial numbers?

Comment: This is not a good question in my opinion. You could just as easily ask why didn't the Eagles just fly Frodo to Mt Doom.  Well because there wouldn't have been a story to tell if they had.

Comment: The story as told makes it pretty clear that Tesla thought the machine didn't work as he'd intended, more or less, right up until Edison's men came and trashed his place.  Angier only discovers the pile of cloned hats because they try it on a cat -- strongly implied to be the first "live subject" trial -- the cat-clone meowing leads him into the woods.  The implication is that while the machine has been cloning successfully for some time, no one knew it because they hadn't discovered the "destination" of the machine until Angier heard the cat.

Answer (score 17):

Apart from the obvious explanation that this was just not considered in the story and wouldn't have fit there, there is evidence from the movie itself and its depiction of *Nikola Tesla*.

*Tesla* was **afraid of the machine's power** once he realized what he actually created there. Remember that when he gives it to *Angier* he also writes something similar to

> The only advice for the machine's usage I can give to you is, destroy it!

So *Tesla* built that thing for him, but he also realized how much power this thing actually conveys and the potential danger this machine poses outweights *Angier*'s possible use from it. I think he mentioned before that he thinks humanity might not be ready for all his ideas, and this machine is an instance of that.

One might ask then, why he still gave it to *Angier* instead of just destroying it right away or not finishing it at all. But I'd assume it is partly his pride in having achieved such a scientific breakthrough as well as his inclination to honor the contract and promise he gave *Angier*. In addition to that it might also support the common motif of the scientist who only realized the true danger of his invention after the fact and is reluctant to take full responsibility for it, just let *Angier* take the hard decision to destroy such an amazing technological achievement.

Last but not least, *Tesla* didn't seem too inclined in making money by dirty tricks instead of by genuine appreciation of his developments. **He wasn't really the person who did all this to make a fast dollar**, but for the progress of mankind and if he would take money, then because his products are well-received and appreciated, but not just by misusing them to produce "dirty" money. In this regard he might indeed be seen as a worse businessman compared to *Edison*, who didn't always play fair afterall. (And in turn this contrast between Tesla and Edison is also used in the movie to [emphasize the rivaly between Borden and Angier](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36460/49).)

Answer (score 11):

From the script:

> TESLA (VO)
>
> Alley has written you a thorough set of instruction.  I add only one
>   suggestion on using the machine - Destroy it. Drop it to the bottom 
>   of the deepest ocean.
>
> Such a thing will only bring you misery.

It appears that Tesla is either frightened of the machine, or is pragmatically recognizing that the power such a machine offers is unlike anything in the world and could result in ruin for the owner or even more widely.

It is speculation, but perhaps Tesla realizes the temptation to make unlimited resources would become an end in itself - while he struggles to make a name for his technology in the world, perhaps he would rather an honest struggle than to follow the temptation of using the device itself.

Comment: It would only be dishonest if Tesla lied about how he made the money. Perhaps he did not want to be put in the situation of having to explain how he suddenly could pay off his debts, and that's why he did not use the machine. Either he becomes a liar or possibly condemned/executed for being the creator of a satanic machine.

Comment: @Sean - the phrase "honest struggle" is not meant to imply using the machine would be dishonest - its meant to imply he would rather be recognized for his talents.  Like you say if he was honest about this, he would at least be called a liar, and if the idea was replicated by less moral people, the machine could be abused.  If someone duplicated gold at the very least they could become the richest person on the planet, at the worst, it could undermine the financial basis of society at the time.

Comment: This is also a good place to reiterate the quote from when Alley first lets Angier into Tesla's compound.  Angier asks why he's being allowed in now, and Alley responds with something along the lines of "you're a magician, nobody would believe anything you tell them anyway".  They know the machine's power is frightening but they also trust that Angier is going to use it for illusions, not to, say, clone an army of perfect warriors or destroy the precious-metals market.

Answer (score 1):

I was always my (perhaps incorrect) assumption that Tesla didn't even know the machine worked.  Remember all the hats out in the forest?  I thought he didn't realize that things re-materialized elsewhere, so he wasn't ever going to step into it.

Working on that assumption, I guess once he discovered exactly what he did then he could have kept going back to the pile of transported money, throwing it back in the machine and then doubling the sum (and on and on...), but by then Angiers had already financed the machine so it really wasn't Tesla's anymore.

Comment: He knew very well what the machine did, but you're right in that he didn't know it immediately. He learned it later, but before he gave it to *Angier*. Once *Angier* found the stuff in the woods he told *Tesla* and they realized what it does.

Comment: Just a thought, but it sure seems like people might take a look at the serial numbers of any 'duplicated' cash, seeing a lot of identical serial numbers would be a way to get yourself in trouble.  You would almost certainly need to duplicate something without any identification like gold/diamonds/silver/etc.

Comment: @Zoredache - I'm not even sure if serial numbers were on currency when that movie was supposed to take place, but in general you're probably right.

Comment: @Zoredache even if period money had serial numbers, if you could scrape together ten or twenty bills (or better yet, borrow 1000 bills for a day) you'd have plenty of serial numbers to shuffle between to avoid short term detection.  Then a money laundering type operation (e.g. a partnership with any money-handling institution) would help to avoid long term detection.  Although I agree duping gold would be excellent as well.

Comment: US Bills have always had serial numbers. The first dollar bills in 1863. Turn of the century 1900s bills would have as well.

Comment: It's definitely strongly suggested that Tesla did not know that the machine really worked at least until after the cat scene.  The film is always hazy with exact timelines but it's strongly suggested that Edison's men destroy his lab very shortly after that scene, so even if he wanted to, say, make himself dozens of duplicated gold bars, he wouldn't have had much time to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Whose to say that the fictional version of Tesla portrayed in The Prestige didn't duplicate large sums of cash prior to leaving Colorado? The movie doesn't show much of what Tesla was up to when Angier wasn't around.

Comment: Typically, Historical figures in fictional movies are assumed to follow their real life histories and personality traits, unless shown otherwise.

Comment: @cde Except real-life Tesla never had such machine.

Comment: That we know of

Comment: I think the implied scope of any question on this site is "...during the time in which the film takes place".  Maybe we'll get a *Prestige 2: Electric Boogaloo* where Tesla uses his stacks of duplicated diamonds to build an even bigger cloning machine a few years later?